# Как сделать карту зависимой от options

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html5

Есть такой код, не обращайте внимания большой объем, суть вопроса просто , как сделать чтобы карта менялась зависимо от options , пока получается сделать только одно изменение на все options

```js
$('#select-town').on('change', function () {
var value = $(this).val();
$('.map-local-block iframe').attr('src','https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d255987.65219667164!2d30.044878901459896!3d59.9171483236945!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4696378cc74a65ed%3A0x6dc7673fab848eff!2z0KHQsNC90LrRgi3Qn9C10YLQtdGA0LHRg9GA0LM!5e0!3m2!1sru!2sru!4v1484834565398');
$('.select-addres').attr('hidden', 'true');
$('#' + value).removeAttr('hidden');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="flag-block ">
      <img src="/local/templates/empty/img/rus.jpg" alt="flag">
      <a href="#" class="rus-flag active-flag">Россия</a>
      <img src="/local/templates/empty/img/kazah.jpg" alt="flag">
      <a href="#" class="kazah-flag">Казахстан</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-wrap ">
     <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-none-two">
      <div class="map-local-block ">
       <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1OdegHwbyqFMmzLeMvSth-_h2IEE&hl=ru" width="100%" height="540" style='border: none;'></iframe>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 scroll-block  col-sm-4">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class='select-block'>
       <select name="City-scroll" id="select-town">
        <option value="tolyati" >Тольятти</option>
        <option value="moscow" selected>Москва</option>
        <option value="piter" id='piter-options'>Санкт-Петербург</option>
        <option value="perm">Перьм</option>
       </select>
      </div>
     </div>
      
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 scroll-block col-sm-4 scroll-block-two" style='padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;'>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="scroll-block_adress ">
        <div class="adress-text_block">
         <div class="top_name">
          <a href="#" >ООО «Эстетика»</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tel_and_street">
         <span>ул. Мечникова, 12.</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 26-04-05</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 30-43-46</span>
         <br></div>
        <div class="giper_bottom">
         <a href="#">www.mango-s.ru</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="scroll-block_adress">
        <div class="adress-text_block">
         <div class="top_name">
          <a href="#">ООО «Академия эстетики»</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tel_and_street">
         <span>ул. Московская, 101.</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 26-04-05</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 30-43-46</span>
         <br></div>
        <div class="giper_bottom">
         <a href="#">www.mango-s.ru</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="scroll-block_adress">
        <div class="adress-text_block">
         <div class="top_name">
          <a href="#">ИП Ривзанова Р. Х.</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tel_and_street">
         <span>ул. Центральная, 55.</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 26-04-05</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 30-43-46</span>
         <br></div>
        <div class="giper_bottom">
         <a href="#">www.mango-s.ru</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="scroll-block_adress ">
        <div class="adress-text_block">
         <div class="top_name">
          <a href="#" >ООО «Эстетика»</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tel_and_street">
         <span>ул. Мечникова, 12.</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 26-04-05</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 30-43-46</span>
         <br></div>
        <div class="giper_bottom">
         <a href="#">www.mango-s.ru</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     <div class="select-addres" hidden id="moscow">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="scroll-block_adress">
        <div class="adress-text_block">
         <div class="top_name">
          <a href="#" >ООО «Эстетика» москва</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tel_and_street">
         <span>ул. Мечникова, 12.</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 26-04-05</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 30-43-46</span>
         <br></div>
        <div class="giper_bottom">
         <a href="#">www.mango-s.ru</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="scroll-block_adress">
        <div class="adress-text_block">
         <div class="top_name">
          <a href="#">ООО «Академия эстетики»</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tel_and_street">
         <span>ул. Московская, 101.</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 26-04-05</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 30-43-46</span>
         <br></div>
        <div class="giper_bottom">
         <a href="#">www.mango-s.ru</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="scroll-block_adress">
        <div class="adress-text_block">
         <div class="top_name">
          <a href="#">ИП Ривзанова Р. Х.</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tel_and_street">
         <span>ул. Центральная, 55.</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 26-04-05</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 30-43-46</span>
         <br></div>
        <div class="giper_bottom">
         <a href="#">www.mango-s.ru</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="select-addres" hidden id="piter">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="scroll-block_adress">
        <div class="adress-text_block">
         <div class="top_name">
          <a href="#" >ООО «Эстетика» питер</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tel_and_street">
         <span>ул. Мечникова, 12.</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 26-04-05</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 30-43-46</span>
         <br></div>
        <div class="giper_bottom">
         <a href="#">www.mango-s.ru</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="scroll-block_adress">
        <div class="adress-text_block">
         <div class="top_name">
          <a href="#">ООО «Академия эстетики»</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tel_and_street">
         <span>ул. Московская, 101.</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 26-04-05</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 30-43-46</span>
         <br></div>
        <div class="giper_bottom">
         <a href="#">www.mango-s.ru</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="scroll-block_adress">
        <div class="adress-text_block">
         <div class="top_name">
          <a href="#">ИП Ривзанова Р. Х.</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tel_and_street">
         <span>ул. Центральная, 55.</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 26-04-05</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 30-43-46</span>
         <br></div>
        <div class="giper_bottom">
         <a href="#">www.mango-s.ru</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="select-addres" hidden id="perm">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="scroll-block_adress">
        <div class="adress-text_block">
         <div class="top_name">
          <a href="#" >ООО «Эстетика» пермь</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tel_and_street">
         <span>ул. Мечникова, 12.</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 26-04-05</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 30-43-46</span>
         <br></div>
        <div class="giper_bottom">
         <a href="#">www.mango-s.ru</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="scroll-block_adress">
        <div class="adress-text_block">
         <div class="top_name">
          <a href="#">ООО «Академия эстетики»</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tel_and_street">
         <span>ул. Московская, 101.</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 26-04-05</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 30-43-46</span>
         <br></div>
        <div class="giper_bottom">
         <a href="#">www.mango-s.ru</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="scroll-block_adress">
        <div class="adress-text_block">
         <div class="top_name">
          <a href="#">ИП Ривзанова Р. Х.</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tel_and_street">
         <span>ул. Центральная, 55.</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 26-04-05</span>
         <br>
         <span>+7 (8412) 30-43-46</span>
         <br></div>
        <div class="giper_bottom">
         <a href="#">www.mango-s.ru</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-none col-xs-12">
      <div class="map-local-block ">
       <iframe src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/frame/v1/-/CZTARU4W" width="100%" height="690" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вам надо иметь ключь, для подключения своего сайта к сервису гугл мапс.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyCJop1zi8WAqUt-5gCigUmPXAcqNgu5H-8&q=
```

В коде добавляем параметер из селекта в "q"

```
$('#select-town').on('change', function () 
{
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('.map-local-block iframe').attr('src','https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyCJop1zi8WAqUt-5gCigUmPXAcqNgu5H-8&q='+ value);
    $('.select-addres').attr('hidden', 'true');
    $('#' + value).removeAttr('hidden');
})
```

Comment: Можете исправить мой код так, чтобы хоть один options работал как надо, я просто начинающий в js)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: все работает, просто поменяйте javascript код, на мой, и напишите свой ключь

Comment: YOUR_API_KEY поменяйте на код от гугла

Comment: $('.map-local-block iframe').attr('src','https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyCJop1zi8WAqUt-5gCigUmPXAcqNgu5H-8&q='+ value);

Comment: исправил код, только теперь не карта появляется а мой сайт в iframe
Как сделать, чтобы карта появлялось ?

Comment: что вы прописали в iframe src

Comment: Все получилось , а как туда добавить свою карту ? Созданную в google maps ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

Comment: То есть для каждой карты прописывать огромный код ? А импортировать как нибудь уюе готовую карту нельзя ? 

Эту например - https://www.google.ru/maps/@55.8124393,37.7756246,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!6m1!1s1OdegHwbyqFMmzLeMvSth-_h2IEE?hl=ru

Comment: Просто до меня не доходит, как сделать разные карты с макерами + нельзя убирать iframe потому что он используется в другом блоке

Comment: надо кастумизировать карту с параметрами которые они дают

Comment: ну как заработало?